# Dog screaming help stop it

Tags: dogs, behavior

I have the same problem. I have three female dogs 4 year old and two 2 year old sisters. My 4 year old dog screams bloody murder loud as hell when I go to take my other dogs outside. Even if she goes first she would scream. We have to separate the 4 year old because she is aggressive towards other dogs and has an accident where she attacked my husband. I live in Texas and most vets or animal shelters cannot take her so we are just stuck. I don't know how to make the screaming to stop. Food has her attention for a bit until she sees or hears the door open she starts screaming her bloody murder scream. This been happening since she was about 1 year old. Neighbors has complain especially when she goes out late at night. Someone help me what can I do?

Comment: I think you need a professional dog trainer to give you some advice. This seems to be a deep-seated issue that has been going on for a while.

Comment: Maybe (as a first aid), if she frightens you, your husband or the other dogs, you can use a (comfortable!) muzzle to be more relaxed in handling her. She senses your feelings, and it can be an advantage, if you stay calm while handling her.  With a good fitting muzzle she can comfortably drink, pant and even get treats from your hands. I read an answer here, handling this topic. I will comment it here as soon as I find it.

Comment: In this answer the reason is aggressiv behaviour because of trauma. But I could imagine, that aggressive behaviour because of fear can get a similar first aid (muzzle&calm down) until the steps taken with a dog trainer start to work. https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/37355/how-to-stop-unpredictable-aggressive-behaviour-in-a-rescued-dog/37357#37357

Answer (score 4):

This sounds like deeply rooted fear and anxiety, especially if your dog has attacked a known person previously. I would recommend starting by researching handling fear aggression in dogs and if at all possible would recommend looking into professional dog trainers who specialize in fear aggression.

I know this isn't the answer you were hoping for, but if she has already attacked someone she knows, it is only likely to get worse without professional help, and could become really dangerous for any person exposed to her, for your other dogs, and for her.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like your 4-year-old dog may be experiencing anxiety or fear when you take the other dogs out, which is causing her to scream. It's important to address this behavior, both for her well-being and for the well-being of your household and neighbors. Here are some suggestions:

1. Consult with a certified dog behaviorist: A certified dog behaviorist can help identify the root cause of your dog's behavior and create a customized behavior modification plan to address it. They may also be able to help you find resources for rehoming if necessary.
2. Provide mental and physical stimulation: Make sure your dogs are getting enough mental and physical exercise throughout the day. This may include walking, playing, training, and providing puzzle toys.
3. Create a safe space: Consider creating a safe space for your 4-year-old dog, such as a crate or a separate room, where she can retreat to when she feels anxious or overwhelmed.
4. Use positive reinforcement: Reward your dog with treats or praise when she exhibits calm behavior, such as not screaming when you take the other dogs out. This will help reinforce the behavior you want to see and may help reduce her anxiety.
5. Consider medication: In some cases, medication may be necessary to help manage your dog's anxiety. Talk to your veterinarian about whether this may be appropriate for your dog.

It's important to address this behavior as soon as possible to ensure the safety and well-being of all the dogs in your household and your neighbors.